# How do you combine different columns of different tables using SELECT and JOIN in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables `Table1, Table2, and Table3`. In each table, I have the columns `primaryKey (unsigned int), and name`. I am trying to make a query using `SELECT` statement and get the table that contains the name of Table1, name of Table2, and name of Table3. I have this code so far:

```
SELECT Table1.name as Table1Name, Table2.name as Table2Name, Table3.name as Table3Name
from Table1 INNER JOIN table2 on 
table1.primaryKey = table2.primaryKey;
```

I get this error:

```
Error 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Table3.name' in 'field list'
```

I probably have the syntax wrong but I can't seem to figure it out! I got two tables to work but not 3 :( all help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: remove table3.name or add table 3 in join part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to list Table3 in your "FROM" clause:

```
SELECT Table1.name as Table1Name, Table2.name as Table2Name, Table3.name as Table3Name
from Table1 INNER JOIN table2 on 
table1.primaryKey = table2.primaryKey
INNER JOIN table3 on
table1.primaryKey = table3.primaryKey;
```

Comment: I knew I was missing that I wasn't sure what the syntax was. This makes more sense now thank you!

Comment: @user2921302 You just add on another table like that. If your primary keys are all the same you don't need to specify all 3 "on" clauses, only 2.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you didn't join your `Table3`. you only join the `table`1 and `table2`..

```
SELECT Table1.name as Table1Name, Table2.name as Table2Name, Table3.name as Table3Name
from Table1 INNER JOIN table2 on 
table1.primaryKey = table2.primaryKey
INNER JOIN table3 on table2.primaryKey = table3.primaryKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do one more INNER JOIN with table 3 as well

```
SELECT Table1.name as Table1Name, Table2.name as Table2Name, Table3.name as Table3Name
from table1 INNER JOIN table2 on 
table1.primaryKey = table2.primaryKey INNER JOIN table3 on table1.primaryKey = table3.primaryKey;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have Table3 in the from clause.

Answer (score -2):

You have forgotten the Table3 in the select query.

```
SELECT Table1.name as Table1Name, Table2.name as Table2Name, Table3.name as Table3Name
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.primaryKey = Table2.primaryKey
INNER JOIN Table3 on Table1.primaryKey  = Table3.primaryKey;
```

**or**

```
SELECT Table1.name as Table1Name, Table2.name as Table2Name, Table3.name as Table3Name 
FROM Table1, Table2, Table3 WHERE table1.primaryKey = table2.primaryKey AND  
table1.primaryKey  = t3.primaryKey;
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: you have invalid syntax for the first query and you should not recommend someone uses the pre ANSI syntax.

Comment: Sorry wrongly type. i correct it now.